# PHPUnit: testing parameter types

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I want to test a method that can take, as a parameter, either an instance of class `Foo` or a string. If anything else is passed it throws an `Exception`.

How do I test that if I don't pass one of the valid types the exception is thrown? How can I make sure that anything other than one of those types will yield an exception?

Comment: Add a call to `$this->expectException(WhateverTheException::class)` and call your method with the wrong parameter type. Check out https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/8.0/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#testing-exceptions

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on my comment on the OP - you can use `expectException()` to tell PHPUnit that you want to assert that an exception is thrown in the following test. See https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/8.0/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#testing-exceptions

Example:

```
public function testExceptionIsThrown()
{
    $this->expectException(WhateverTheException::class);

    $class = new ClassToTest;
    $class->methodToTest(1); // an integer is not a string or an instance of Foo and should throw an exception
}
```

Comment: I know what you mean and my tests are somewhat like that. But what if I pass a float? or a bool? or an instance of some other class? I want to test **any** other data types. Can it be done?

Comment: Is that logic in your class method? Something like `if (!($value instanceof Foo || is_string($value))) { throw new \Exception('nope'); }` If so, you wouldn't really need to test much more. Just a couple of fails and a pass.

Comment: Yes it's something like that. Thanks.